# Bizarre Behavior with Markdown Filter and Cache Clearing

Tags: 7, caching, input-formats

We are trying to allow Markdown input on long text fields for certain content types. It is proving difficult. Here is what I have done:

1. Installed [Markdown filter](https://www.drupal.org/project/markdown) module.
2. Added a new Text Format in Configuration -> Content Authoring -> Text Formats.
3. Edited the text fields on our "Lesson Plan" content type so that the user can select "Markdown" text format.

That should be everything I have to do, right?

---

**BUT WAIT --** number 2 above is giving me very strange behavior!

- In my "Markdown" text format configuration page, I can't see the Markdown option *unless I first clear all the caches while I am on that page*.
- After I have cleared the cache, the Markdown checkbox shows up, and I can select it.
- But after hitting "Save Configuration", *the option disappears*, and none of my content formats correctly when I try to select the Markdown text format.

Why is this happening? I don't know where to start looking!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed the problem. I don't know why it acted the way it did, but it started working after I deleted the markdown folder in sites/all/modules, and re-installed using the "official" /admin/modules page (which is SSL enabled).